# How to add a value from a cookie to the HTTP header in Spring WebServiceTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-ws

I am using Spring [WebServiceTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html) in my client side code to send request to an existing 3rd party web service.

```
<bean id="vehicleQuotationWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="vehicleQuotationMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="vehicleQuotationMarshaller" />
    <property name="faultMessageResolver" ref="vehicleServiceClientFaultMessageResolver" />
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:8080/quote/endpoints"/>
</bean>
```

Everything was working fine until they added security check from the server side. Right now, in order to pass the server side security authenication, I need to pass some values from a cookie to the server. This I can do easily in SoapUI by modifying the http header (adding the cookie's value there), but my question is how can I do it in Java code with the Spring's `WebServiceTemplate`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the `WebServiceTemplate` or in a more easy way use a custom sender who extends Spring's

```
org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender
```

and set in your bean definition

```
<bean id="vehicleQuotationWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="vehicleQuotationMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="vehicleQuotationMarshaller" />
    <property name="faultMessageResolver" ref="vehicleServiceClientFaultMessageResolver" />
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:8080/quote/endpoints"/>
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MyHttpComponentsMessageSender"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

take a look at Spring forums

[JSESSIONID and setting cookie for WebServiceTemplate](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/39225-jsessionid-and-setting-cookie-for-webservicetemplate)

Comment: Thanks, looks exactly like what I am looking for. I took a look at the codes there, how can I get the HttpServletRequest srequest = (HttpServletRequest) ((this.getPageContext()).getRequest()) out of the client? "this" means the client here, right?

Comment: Your server should be return the cookie to the client after calling a login method or something like that.

Comment: no, the server isn't going to send me the cookie. what i am trying to do is to set the credentials (which is known) with the messageSender so that the request can pass the server authentication. Is there anyway I can do it?

Comment: I figured it out, actually it is much easier that if i don't need to get cookie from the server. I just set the cookie name and value in the client that nails it. Thanks a lot, vzamanillo!